# symfony2 doctrine windows to linux server migration

Tags: windows, linux, symfony, doctrine, migration

I have developed a `symfony2` application using `admingenerator` module and it works well on my `XAMPP` server on windows.

Moving the whole application including db on a linux server brakes doctrine (presumably).

The application (with errors) can be found [here](http://quipod.com/bion/admin/web/app_dev.php/users/)

Having seen a few posts regarding migration issues to linux (perhaps due to different folder notations `\` vs `/`), I wasn't able to find a fix.

Anyone with similiar problems ?

P.S: If prompted for credentials user admin / pass admin!

Comment: can you clear your app/cache and check ?

Comment: hi thx for the answer. i have tried app/console cache:clear and warmup  .but it halts with some error:
"  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]
  You have requested a non-existent service "admingenerator.generator.doctrine_odm".
"
i did however deleted the whole cache folder content.

I thing warming up / clearing the cache might solve the issue but i can't run any because of the up-mentioned error. Most probably, i am not using that "service" but seems to be mentioned somewhere, how could i remove it somehow ? 

Thx once more,
Ion

Answer (score 3):

Look at your file at Shlomi\UsersBundle\Entity\users. 
Is it Users.php or users.php? Remember that Linux is case sensitive and Windows not.

Comment: Exactly! THx for the answer. Indeed this was the problem and it is now solved.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways that I migrate a Symfony environment is to run SED against the whole database dump.  So for example, if I was going from xampp to mywebsite.com I would do the following

```
%>sed -i bak 's/oldhost/newhost/g' myfile
```

For Windows you may have to do a similar path replacement to change the '\' to '/'.

Also, there may be some additional steps required for Symfony.  See here:

http://robbymillsap.tumblr.com/post/21579085155/sed-find-replace-on-osx

Hope that helps.

Comment: thx for the answer. 
what do you mean running it against the sql dump ? as i assume the changes must be done only on the source files (and only in some places) thx